# Vote/View count abnormality

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, views

How can a post be viewed 7 times and downvoted 8 times? Is it a bug?

[image: vote-view-difference]

Comment: I don't think that view counter is completely up-to-date. I've seen minor (~ 1 min.) delays before it actually increments.

Comment: Votes are updated automagically...views are not. Nothing to see here. Additionally: Caching. Can you still repro this?

Comment: Maybe it's a **really** terrible question?

Comment: The question was removed. It was spam. [this is the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143711/when-the-sun-a-lot-of-time-if-you-really-want-to-bring-a-sunglasses-to-go-out)

Comment: [For everyone with 10k](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143711/when-the-sun-a-lot-of-time-if-you-really-want-to-bring-a-sunglasses-to-go-out). The votes are at -9, views are at 8 at the moment.

Comment: @WaffelizedBobby It's removed removed :)

Comment: When I jump to a very old question with low views, it usually takes a few refreshes before it registers my view. On the flip side, when a question is hot on Reddit, every single refresh (even seconds apart) has a higher view count. So the updates aren't being "batched". They just lag.

Comment: Hm, can't see if the question is closed or not, but off topic and not a real question closures cast an automatic downvote...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The view counter on posts is a bit of a liberal approximation, by design.  [Stack Overflow gets a lot of pageviews](http://quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com) and it's easier to just drop a few views every now and then than try to make it 100% accurate.

Comment: Also note that we only count unique IPs, so two users from the same company would only count as one view.